# Throwing FormCancelledException from await instead of AggregateException in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

I'm  currently trying to test the following code in an application that makes use of the Microsoft Bot Framework.

```
public async Task ResumeAfterCalculation_v2FormDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Calculation_v2Form> result)
{
    try
    {
        var extractedCalculationForm = await result;
        //Removed additional code
    }
    catch (FormCanceledException ex)
    {
        var reply = "You have canceled the operation.";
        await _chat.PostAsync(context, reply);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
}
```

When a user types 'quit' to the bot the 'await result' code throws a FormCanceledException and the code quits the form.

When creating a test I implemented a class to mock the IAwaitable:

```
public class TaskAwaiterHelper<T> : IAwaiter<T>, IAwaitable<T>
{
    public Task<T> Task { get; }

    public TaskAwaiterHelper(T obj)
    {
        this.Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(obj);
    }

    public TaskAwaiterHelper(Task<T> task)
    {
        this.Task = task;
    }

    public bool IsCompleted { get { return Task.IsCompleted; } }

    public void OnCompleted(Action action)
    {
        SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        TaskScheduler scheduler = context == null ? TaskScheduler.Current
            : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Task.ContinueWith(ignored => action(), scheduler);
    }

    public T GetResult()
    {
        return Task.Result;
    }

    public IAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I then created the following test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ResumeAfterCalculation_v2FormDialog_WasCancelled_ThenCallsDone()
{
    //Arrange
    var chat = new Mock<IChatHelper>();
    var calculationApi = new Mock<ICalculationApi>();
    var dialogContextMock = new Mock<IDialogContext>();
    var rootLuisDialog = new RootLuisDialog(chat.Object, calculationApi.Object);

    var taskAwaiter = new TaskAwaiterHelper<Calculation_v2Form>(new Task<Calculation_v2Form>(() =>
    {
        throw new FormCanceledException("Error created for test test", null);
    }));

    taskAwaiter.Task.Start();

    //Act
    await rootLuisDialog.ResumeAfterCalculation_v2FormDialog(dialogContextMock.Object, taskAwaiter);

    //Assert
    chat.Verify(c => c.PostAsync(dialogContextMock.Object, "You have canceled the operation."), Times.Once());

    dialogContextMock.Verify(t => t.Done<object>(null), Times.Once());
}
```

Now whatever I try to do I the exception that's being thrown in the IAwaitable is being wrapped in an AggregateException, so we always end up in the catch (Exception ex) instead of the desired catch (FormCanceledException ex)

Is there a way to make a Task throw a specific Exception instead of an AggregateException (I mean there should be as the bot framework itself seems to be able to do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer, I basically created a new class:

```
public class ExceptionThrower : IAwaitable<Calculation_v2Form>
{
    public IAwaiter<Calculation_v2Form> GetAwaiter()
    {
        throw new FormCanceledException("Error created for test test", null);
    }
}
```

And just provided this to the method:

```
var exceptionThrower = new ExceptionThrower();

await rootLuisDialog.ResumeAfterCalculation_v2FormDialog(dialogContextMock.Object, exceptionThrower);
```